# Show an applicatio non top of a Direct X game?

Tags: directx, video-capture, topmost

Is it possible to build an application that displays itself (TopMost) even when a game is running (Quake, Farcry, Black Ops, any Direct X driven game)

I would like to be able to record my key presses while I play a game for video recording.

It must be possible because FRAPS displays the FPS on top of everything that uses direct X, including video players.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it isn't that easy. FRAPs works with API-Injection, to set some code into the drawing-steps of the programs, where it takes the many different versions of directx and opengl into account. If found a link, where it is explained a little more: [Case Study Fraps](http://www.ring3circus.com/blog/2007/11/22/case-study-fraps/).

Maybe a solution to work in windowed mode and capture the input with global hooks is easier, but I never tried out something in this direction. If you want to work with api-hooks maybe this link will be useful: [Direct3DHook](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook)